# Go to grandparent state with ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

With `ui-router` I can use `$state.go('^')` to go to parent state without having to specify it's full path. Is there similar way to go to grandparent state (my parent state is abstract)?

In [documentation examples](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state) I can see only `^` for parent, but maybe someone has good solution for this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can transition to the grandparent state with

```
$state.go('^.^')
```

Comment: Ah, I tried `^^` and even `.go('^').go('^')`. I was pretty sure I tried also the one you wrote but probably I gave up, thinking it won't work... Tomorrow I'll check if it works and accept the answer. Thanks!

Comment: That looks like a happy little bear face