# ui-sref using ^. to navigate to higher parents

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Like the title suggests, I am using **angular-ui-router**.
I have a state set up like this:

```
.state('home.dashboard.groups.questions.answers.formulas', answerFormulasRoute());
```

When on that route I can use the **ui-sref** like this:

```
<li><a ui-sref="^.">Answers</a></li>
```

Which will give me the parent state (from where I am).
To get further down the path I have to do something like this:

```
<li><a ui-sref="home">Home</a></li>
<li><a ui-sref="home.dashboard">{{ controller.category.name }}</a></li>
<li><a ui-sref="home.dashboard.groups">Groups</a></li>
<li><a ui-sref="home.dashboard.groups.questions">Questions</a></li>
```

I was wondering if there was a way if using the `^.` to get to home?
Maybe something like

```
<li><a ui-sref="^.....">Home</a></li>
```

Does anyone know of a way?

Comment: You mean, aside from <a ui-sref="home"></a> ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26741345/go-to-grandparent-state-with-ui-router => ^.^ (this is not smile...)